# How to use linked-in j library to get current user details

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-j

I am using linked-in j library.
I am able to connect with linked-in but when i go for details for the profile of current user then i get whole Person object but this object only contain the values of first name, last name and headline.And other values are null.
But when i go to my linked-in public profile their i can see the skills, college etc.
My application have full access.

Answer (score 0):

I think you never set ProfileField's in enum
Please try like this,

```
  Set<ProfileField> propertiesToFetch = EnumSet.of(ProfileField.ID,
            ProfileField.FIRST_NAME, ProfileField.LAST_NAME,
            ProfileField.HEADLINE, ProfileField.PICTURE_URL,
            ProfileField.DATE_OF_BIRTH, ProfileField.PHONE_NUMBERS,
            ProfileField.MAIN_ADDRESS, ProfileField.INDUSTRY,
            ProfileField.EDUCATIONS, ProfileField.LANGUAGES_LANGUAGE_NAME,
            ProfileField.SKILLS_SKILL_NAME,
            ProfileField.CERTIFICATIONS_NAME, ProfileField.POSITIONS_TITLE,
            ProfileField.POSITIONS_COMPANY_NAME,
            ProfileField.POSITIONS_COMPANY);
    Person profile = client.getProfileForCurrentUser(propertiesToFetch);
```